# Do the images in the assets folder also get deployed in a Vue project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, deployment, vuejs2, web-deployment

Hello guys so as you can see from the title this is my first time working on a project. I’m using Vue, so when I deploy after running the “npm run build” and uploading the index.html.

Where does the assets folder go, I have a lot of images in it and I’m referencing them in my project. Does any of this change after deployment?

Comment: I am not familiar with vue, but I have tried svelte. It depends on what the build script is in your `package.json`. Usually a new folder (e.g. `dist`) will be created containing everything to be deployed on the server. Uploading index.html is usually not enough.

Comment: Yeah, I believe you are correct. thank you so much for your feedback